# How it works the security in gRPC?

Tags: c#, grpc

I have a service that I am configurating in this way:

```
options.Listen(miAddress, 5001, l =>
{
    l.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 miCertificado = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(@"certificados\service.crt");
    l.UseHttps(miCertificado);
});
```

But if I realized that I can configure the client to avoid the authentication, with this code:

```
var httpClientHandler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
    System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(_serviceAddress,
    new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });
var client = new Gestor.GestorClient(channel);
```

In this case, the authentications is ignored and I can use call to the service.

I know that this ignore the authentication because if I try to use the client to use a certificate, I get an error that tells that the connection couldn't be stablish because of the SSL.

So my doubt is, there is some way to set the service to don't allow this kind of connections? If not, anyone could create a client that igonres this authentication and the security has no sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTTPS is not the same as using authentication. All you're doing is encrypting the traffic between client and server, so that eavesdroppers can't read your plaintext traffic.

If you configure your client to accept any server certificate, whether that certificate is valid up till its root or not, does not "ignore authentication" - there was no authentication to begin with.

Comment: But isn't the certificates used to create the credentials? And insn't credetials used to be authenticated?

Comment: Certificates can be used for multiple things. The code you show, doesn't use certificates for client authentication. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1.